# IF ELSE in OOP PHP

Tags: php, arrays, oop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am writing an if else statement in OOP;

The conditions are:

```
1. Get all  requests from BSC from 789789 or 987897
2. If RNB is starting 17 and are 15 characters long
3. Those values with cost as 15 send to URL 1
4. Else send to URL 2
```

If it matches the statement it is sent to a specific URL, if it does not it sent to another URL. I have rewritten the conditional statement below:

```
if($request->BSC = 789789 or 987897 && $request->RNB = 17 && $request->BRN strlen = 15 && $request->Cost = 11){
    send to URL 1
} else{
    ..Send to URL 2
}
```

My question is conditional statement correct?

Comment: Your conditional statement has obvious syntax errors.

Comment: are u asking about oops or u have doubt in if else statement. there is error in ur if part

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=`,   `||` instead of `or` in if statement

Comment: @black I have doubts in the if else statements which am writing in OOP

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki  thanks so is this statement correct?: if($request->BSC == 789789 || 987897 && $request->RNB ==17 && $request->BRN strlen == 15 && $request->Cost ==11)

Comment: Please clarify this sentence a little more :  `If RNB is starting 17 and are 15 characters long` , what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Consider removing “arrays” and “oop” tags as not really relevant to your question, — one should not just pick some 5 applicable terms.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear,

I try to fix your `if` statement just to show you the correct syntax!:

```
if( ($request->BSC == 789789 || $request->BSC == 987897) &&  strpos($request->RNB,'7') == 0  && $request->BRN == 15&& $request->Cost == 11){
    //send to URL 1
} else{
    //send to URL 2
}
```

This line :

```
  strpos($request->RNB,'7') == 0
```

Means:    RNB should start with `7`, for example : 765433 or 789998 or 712342 . ..

Comment: sure let me clarifiy in $Request->RNB , the 17 should actually be 7 where the RNB value  starts with 7 (value posted in the db);  and the variable BRN should be RNB  instead. Can you edit your answer. I appreciate your effort!